# Issue while using customized list view with Arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview

```
    private void dataCollection() {
    ArrayList<BreachHistoryData> responselist = SessionClass.getResponseList();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.breachHistoryLstView);
    View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_breach_history_header, null);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);

    for (BreachHistoryData breachHistoryData : responselist) {
        messageView= new MessageView[] { new MessageView(breachHistoryData.getDate(), breachHistoryData.getTime(),breachHistoryData.getBreachNo(),breachHistoryData.getFee(), null) };

    }
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,R.layout.custom_breach_history_items, messageView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In the above code i have around 100 values in responselist . But when i try
 to add those values in my list view it always adding the last value of the responselist(ArraList). Its working fine when i print the values. But Adding the values into the list view only have some issues.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please show the code for your adapter

Comment: what kind of issue you are facing

Comment: Am getting only the last value of the arraylist. In case am printing the arraylist, it prints all the value. The problem is only when i add the arraylist into the list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you only have one messageView and it is being reused for every element in you arrayList. This means that only the last item will be in it when the for loop finishes and that is why your adapter is only showing the last item. you either need an array of messageView or add each message view to the adapter before the loop executes again.

Comment: I added messageView in to the loop.Then also am getting same result.. How can i fix this issue. Help me to overcome from this.. Thanks

Comment: but `messageView` gets over written every time the loop executes. Meaning the last thing to overwrite it is the last item in your arrayList